# Not a GROUP BY expression SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Подскажите, почему GROUP BY выдаёт ошибку not a GROUP BY expression

```
 WITH LNK AS
(SELECT ART.ITEM_OLD, ART.ITEM_NEW, ART.Format, ART.Cardinality FROM EXT.T_ANALOGUE_RULES_TMP ART
WHERE ART.Cardinality<(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT format) FQty FROM scpomgr.ut_jda_formats)),
INV AS
(SELECT I.Loc DC,I.Item Item_Old, SUM(I.Qty) INV_OLD FROM SCPOMGR.INVENTORY I
JOIN SCPOMGR.LOC L ON I.Loc=L.LOC
WHERE L.Loc_Type=3 AND I.availdate <= system_date
AND I.expdate > system_date
AND I.Qty>0
AND I.item in (select item_old from LNK)
GROUP BY I.Loc,I.Item),
T1 AS
(SELECT SRC.Source DC,SRC.ITEM ITEM,LNK.Format Format,LNK.Item_Old Item_Old,LNK.Cardinality Cardinality FROM SCPOMGR.sourcing SRC
JOIN INV ON INV.DC=SRC.Source
JOIN LNK ON INV.Item_Old=LNK.Item_Old
WHERE Src.u_factor=1
AND SRC.Item=LNK.Item_New
AND SRC.u_Sourcing NOT IN ('CD','PBL','PBS'))
SELECT PA.Loc DC,T1.Item_Old Item_Old,TRUNC(PA.Startdate) ShipDate,T1.Format Format,INV.INV_OLD INV_OLD,(SUM(PA.Planship)/T1.Cardinality) Qty FROM scpomgr.ut_skuprojstatic_ss PA
JOIN T1 ON PA.ITEM=T1.Item
JOIN INV ON INV.Item_Old=T1.Item_Old
WHERE PA.Loc=T1.DC AND INV.DC=T1.DC AND PA.Planship>0
GROUP BY PA.Loc,T1.Item_Old,TRUNC(PA.Startdate),T1.Format,INV.INV_OLD
```

Ругается на последний GROUP BY. Я добавил все поля в него, кроме агрегируемого. По отдельности все таблицы считались. Попробовал выгрузить рандомные данные из последней таблицы таким запросом:

```
SELECT PA.Item,PA.Loc,(SUM(PA.Planship)/PA.Loc) Test FROM scpomgr.ut_skuprojstatic_ss  pa
WHERE PA.Planship>0
GROUP BY PA.Item,PA.Loc
```

Всё работает. А когда собираю весь запрос - not a Group By expression

Comment: `T1.Cardinality` про это не забыли?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка в строке

```
( SUM(PA.Planship) / T1.Cardinality ) Qty
```

`T1.Cardinality` не входит в `GROUP BY` и не задействована в никакой групповой функции.

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо ! Я правильно понимаю, что при использовании GROUP BY необходимо обязательно включать все элементы, которые входили в SELECT ?даже те, которые участвовали в вычислениях с агрегатными функциями ???

Comment: Да, правильно. Колонки не входящие в группировку могут быть только параметрами агрегатных функций.